# What would happen if two liquids of different nature are mixed together?

Tags: fluid-statics, physical-chemistry, surface-tension, capillary-action

I was studying surface tension the other day and this thought came to my mind.

What would happen if say a liquid like mercury which has higher cohesive forces than adhesive ones(hence the convex meniscus) and another like water, which has higher adhesive forces than cohesive ones (hence the concave meniscus) were mixed together in a container? Would the resulting solution have higher cohesive forces or adhesive forces?

Comment: If you shake a bottle containing water & mercury, they separate *very* quickly after you stop shaking.

Comment: Are you thinking the mercury will dissolve into the water?

Comment: Are you asking "What would happen if you mixed mercury and water", or "What would the properties of the homogeneous mixture between two liquids be"?

Comment: I meant take 2 liquids that are miscible but one has greater adhesive force while the other has greater cohesive force

Comment: And i am thinking about the properties of a homogeneous mixture of 2 miscible liquids

Answer (score 1):

they will mot mix together, but will separate into two separate *phases*. In this case, all the mercury globules will draw themselves together into one big glob. There will be a *tiny* amount of mercury dissolved into the water surrounding that glob (that's one *phase*) and a *tiny* amount of water dissolved into the mercury (that's the other *phase*).

Comment: (+1) As a retired chemistry professor, I can verify this is correct.

Answer (score -2):

They won't mix together.They have different densities.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but "different densities" probably is _not_ the reason why two different liquids fail to form a [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution) or an [emulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulsion).

Comment: @SolomonSlow the op clearly states that two liquid forming a solution and as far as i know two different liquids with different densities cant form a solution. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: ...And I don't know why density would matter. Density is a bulk property. A solution is homogeneous at the molecular level, and molecules don't have "density." But I am not an expert. Mostly just an armchair observer here.

Comment: All my rep is from answering newbie questions. It's a different skill from knowing how to do physics.

Comment: Olive oil and vinegar have almost identical densities, yet separate after shaking immediately. Density is NOT the driving force here.

Comment: *And arm chair observer with 5k reputation points* This site has a 'be nice' policy. No snark, please.

Comment: @Gert Will delete it.

Comment: Very well, thanks you.

Comment: @Gert I searched the internet and came up with  this. https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/can-mercury-react-water-what-reaction-744484#:~:text=Mercury%20and%20water%20do%20not,if%20the%20two%20are%20mixed.&text=Mercury%20can%20also%20react%20with,occurring%20and%20corrupting%20your%20mixture.

Comment: @Gert  Please read the above link. If i am wrong , i will delete my answer..

Comment: Please don't link to 'check my homework' sites, they are of VERY limited veracity. Imiscible liquids do not separate because of density although density difference obviously does help.

Comment: There are many water soluble mercury COMPOUNDS. Where does that leave you with your density?

Comment: @Gert But hasn't the op asked about pure liquid mercury rather than mercury compounds?

Comment: @Ohw You obviously haven't read the entire exchange. Zzzzz...